# Migrating Spring Boot DataSource configuration to Hikari CP

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following Datasource configuration in a Spring Boot 1.x application:

```
db1.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/mysqldb
db1.datasource.username=root
db1.datasource.password=password1
db1.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The datasource is injected in the code as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceBeans {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="db1.datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db1.datasource")
    public DataSource db1DataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

I have read that the Connection Pool in Spring Boot 2.x is by default Hikari CP. Should I adjust the source code to return an HikariDataSource ? or it happens automatically (being now the default)

Answer (score 0):

Hikari requires the datasource url to be defined as **spring.datasource.jdbcUrl** where it used to be **spring.datasource.url**.

The spring documentation messes this up in [their example][1] where they incorrectly define the jdbc URL with a dash: **jdbc-url**.

The rest of the spring documentation on how to configure multiple data sources is very useful.